# MAMP PRO 3.0.7 SSL not working

Tags: ssl, mamp-pro

I cannot run any SSL sites on my MAMP PRO installation since I upgraded to v3.07 and OX Yosemite. I create a self signed cert through MAMP, but when I try and start up Apache I get this error:

[Mon Oct 20 14:36:04 2014] [error] Unable to configure permitted SSL ciphers
[Mon Oct 20 14:36:04 2014] [error] SSL Library Error: 336646329 error:1410D0B9:SSL routines:SSL_CTX_set_cipher_list:no cipher match

When I turn SSL off, it works fine. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

The new update v3.0.7.1 has fixed this.